# How to Send Ephemeral Messages in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Make a discord.js bot send ephemeral messages when a user uses a slash command, i have tried using `interation.editReply({content: "etc-etc", ephemeral:true});` ,
and anything that seemed reasonable but it seemed unsuccessful, please send an example how i would implement ephemeral message!

Edit:

My Slash command Help file:

```
const { Message, Client } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "Sends web page url for all commands",
    run: async (client, interaction) => {

        await interaction.deferReply({ephemeral: true});

        interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [
                {
                    title: `${client.user.username}'s Help Page`,
                    description: `https://help.tcb.jayeshrocks.xyz`,
                    color: "RANDOM"
                }
            ]
        })
    }
};
```

Now I am recieving interaction already replied errors

Edit 2: It was an error with my interactionCreate.js and now that i fixed it, it's working with .deferReply() , thanks!

Comment: The way you are implementing `ephemeral: true` is correct, but maybe the `defer` in your `interactionCreate` file is not. 
Can you edit your post and add your `interactionCreate` event file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
await interaction.deferReply({
            ephemeral: true
        });
```

put that underneath this

```
run: async (client, interaction) => {
// your code
}
```

yours might look different

Final. it should look something like this:

```
run: async (client, interaction) => {
        await interaction.deferReply({
            ephemeral: false
        });
// your code
}
```

Comment: interaction.editReply({content: "etc-etc"});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/) you need to add the [`ephemeral` option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) in your [`InteractionReplyOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions). You can also check out Discord.js's [guide about ephemeral responses](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses).

> You may not always want everyone who has access to the channel to see a slash command's response. Thankfully, Discord implemented a way to hide messages from everyone but the executor of the slash command. This type of message is called an `ephemeral` message and can be set by using `ephemeral: true` in the `InteractionReplyOptions`
>
> [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses)

##### Here's an example:

```js
//use the `interaction.reply()` function normally

await interaction.reply({
   embeds: [{
      title: `${client.user.username}'s Help Page`,
      description: `https://help.tcb.jayeshrocks.xyz`,
      color: "RANDOM"
   }],
   //this is the important part
   ephemeral: true
});
```

##### Ephemeral Defer Reply:

You can also use the [`ephemeral` option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) when doing [`deferReply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/BaseCommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply)
.

```js
//use the `interaction.deferReply()` function normally

await interaction.deferReply({
   //this is the important part
   ephemeral: true
});
```

### **Learn More**

- [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses)
- [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions)
- [Discord's Official Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-response-object-messages)